# Reference about connected groupoids and action groupoids

Tags: reference-request, group-actions, groupoids

I need a reference for the assertion that: "any connected groupoid is isomorphic to some action groupoid (of a group action on the set of objects of the groupoid)", as discussed in this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127729/connected-groupoids-and-action-groupoids). Could you please recommend a book or paper?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I’ve found you :)